# Passing a path to a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

First off, I know that this sort of a duplicate, but I believe that my problem is different from the other question on the same topic (read: more n00by).

Basically, I'm trying to use [this script.](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex13/roamcursor.htm) To make my code neater and more easily human-readable, I decided to put it into a seperate script, wrap the whole thing in a function with a `path` parameter, and then call the function (after setting up the script on the main page) with a the path to the image I wanted to use.

My question is pretty basic; what's the correct way to format the path? Do I format the path when I pass it to the function as a string? Right now, what I have isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path will be always a string but the path format depends.

You can use either **relative** or **absolute** path.

I'd recommend you to try the relative path first. For example, if your image is in a parent  folder from your page, use `var cursorpath="../cursor.gif";`.

For absolute paths you need to provide the full path and match the same protocol used for your page. For example, if your image is in `C:/dev/images/cursor.gif` and you're running your page directly from the file, you should use `var cursorpath="file:///C:/dev/images/cursor.gif"`.

Let me know if this solve your problem.

**EDIT**

If the image is in a folder at the same level of your page use:

```
cursorpath="img/cursor.gif"; //Without the '/' in the beginning
```

For example, if we are at the page `http://google.com/search/index.html` and add two `<img>` like this:

```
<img src="images/sample.png">
<img src="/images/sample.png">
```

The first one will search for an image at `http://google.com/search/images/sample.png`.

The second one will try this path beggining from the website root (the `/`), like this `http://google.com/images/sample.png`.

Comment: So I'm trying to use an image in a folder called `img`. The folder is in the same directory as the `index.html` file that I'm calling the function from. In this case, would I use `var cursorpath="/img/cursor.gif";`?

Comment: And, if I'm passing this directory to a function instead of as a variable, would I keep the quotes?

Comment: @evamvid Yes keep the quotes, they can be either double or simple.

Comment: So I would apply this the same way when passing an argument to the function? The original script uses `cursorpath` as a variable. My objective is to wrap it in a function called `cursor`, with path as an argument. `cursorpath` would be set equal to `path`.

Comment: If you declared the function like this: `function cursor(cursorpath){ ... }` you already have the `cursorpath` variable inside that function. So you can call like this: `cursor("img/cursor.gif");`. Got it?

Comment: My function looks something like `var cursor = function(path) { //lots of code};`. Will making it like `var cursor = function(path) { var cursorpath = path; //lots of code };` work? Am I using the argument correctly?

Comment: That works too, but it's not a rule. In both cases you call like this: `cursor("img/cursor.gif");`